# DB for iOS app for a company

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am developing an iOS App which requires to list the employee contact details in a Table View. Any changes made to employee's contact detail, it should reflect on everyone who has an app. Should I be using SQLite or any other DB for this requirement?

Comment: You can also see Wenderlich's companion pieces, [How to Write an App that Uses a Web Service](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service) and [How to Write a Simple PHP/MySQL Web Service for iOS App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite will only solve the local database of your app. You are going to need a server Database to be used by all of your users. The database in the web and the one in the device don't need to be the same at all.

If you are not familiar with web development I would suggest using Parse.com to create your web-service, it's really easy.